# How to replace a string exactly as it is?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
String str = "folder1;b";
String replacement = "C:\\myfolder";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("b", replacement));
```

This prints`C:myfolder`. 
How can I replace str with the replacement string as is? (Without the slashes being removed)
I've tried `Pattern.quote(replacement)` but that prints `\QC:\Development\E`

I have no control over replacement which comes from an external source and it is not known what its contents would be.

Comment: where's the code that does the actual replacement?

Comment: @Reimeus Its in there. I was editing.

Comment: What is the expected output after replacement?

Comment: Or better yet, just use [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead of [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). The former uses literal replacement, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't using regular expressions, better to use [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String str = "folder1;b";
String replacement = "C:\\myfolder";
System.out.println(str.replace("b", replacement));
```

`String.replace()` does a literal replacement, it doesn't treat the arguments as regular expressions.

I will point out that you will run into trouble if your `str` is `folder1;bash;b` as both of the `b`s will be replaced.

Comment: You still need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `String.replaceAll` expect a regex. In the regex world a `\` has a special operator meaning. You have to escape it once for the jvm and once for regex.

```
String str = "b";
String replacement = "C:\\\\\\\\myfolder";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(str, replacement));
```

Will print out

```
C:\\myfolder
```

With `String.replace` it does take the literal string and thus you only have to escape it once for the jvm

```
String str = "b";
String replacement = "C:\\\\myfolder";
System.out.println(str.replace(str, replacement));
```

Will print

```
C:\\myfolder
```

And lastly, if you have no idea how the incoming replacement String looks like you can escape it beforehand with

```
    String str = "b";
    String replacement = "C:\\myfolder"; // might be anything
    String actualReplacement = replacement.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println(str.replace(str, actualReplacement));
```

Will print

```
C:\\myfolder
```

Other than that you could use one of the apache.utils to achieve it, but this one here is without any third party library.

Answer (score 0):

[String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)  uses regex. You don't need that.

Try this:

```
String str = "b";
String replacement = "C:\\myfolder";
System.out.println(str.replace(str,replacement);
```

Comment: No, it's part of the string. The new string will contain the slashes within it.

Comment: Cool he removed his question, now it looks like I'm crazy and talking to myself ^^

Comment: I have similar voices in my head

Comment: Guess it comes with the trade :)